# 2D Grease Pencil Animation: Fill Not Working

Tags: grease-pencil, 2d, osx

so I'm having an issue with the 2D Fill Tool. I draw the face and I've closed off all the gaps and it still will not fill, any idea why? Do I need to draw the head in one line? Is there some setting preventing me from filling? It worked on the eyes and other things, not sure how to fix it or if it's something I accidentally turned on.

[image]
This is the face that I'm trying to Fill[image]
This is how it looks when I up the Gap Closure slightly.[image]This is how it looks when I really up the Gap Closure.

Comment: Which fill tool are you using? The actual fill bucket or the select-fill option?

Comment: I’m using the actual fill bucket. Sometimes it will work fine but then I’ll duplicate that same stroke  and try and fill it but instead of filling, my cursor will turn into a number (either 1 or 2), and nothing will happen. I’ve been messing around with it for a few days now and my current theory is it’s either something to do with the amount of layers I have  turned on (visible), the new object I’ve created or a setting I’ve accidentally turned on because when I create a new .blend file to test, it seems to work fine. Or maybe it’s the material, I really don’t know, bit lost at this point.

Comment: I'm still confused. Which strokes are you duplicating? And what are all the blue lines? As for the fill option, you could try creating a new layer, locking all the others, and filling in your object.

Comment: I’m duplicating say for example, one of the eyes and one will fill and one won’t. 

The blue lines are what happen when I try and fill because I have Gap Closure turned on, they’re meant to indicate gaps or something I think.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks for clarifying. Have you tried turning off Gap Closure?

Comment: Yes, on and off. I think maybe using boundary lines that I remove after can help for the moment but really lost with this tool and also have no clue what the numbers mean when I click. Do you think it's maybe how many gaps it thinks are open?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't have enough information to troubleshoot the problem. Could you please post a screenshot of your entire 2d workspace? That will help me better be able to help you.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/grease_pencil/modes/draw/tools/fill.html

Comment: Thanks so much for your help Starry! Really appreciate it, I think I might have an answer, will post it now.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help. :) Good job finding a solution.

Answer (score 1):

After some testing with a previous older version of Blender on Windows and then going back to my 4.0 Version on Mac it seems that the answer is that Blender thinks the things I'm drawing have unclosed areas. I noticed on the old version 2.9 that the fill tool is different, it has a Leak Size setting instead of the Precision one and seems to fill a lot better. But yeah, long story short, Blender thinks there's too many gaps and won't fill.  [image]